# Creating objects of a class via globals()[]

Tags: python, class, object, global

I realize that what I am trying to do is not recommended but, for now, I am interested in pursuing it so as to better understand how object creation and `globals()[]` work.

In the following code, I am able to convert the three string elements in `varList` into variables by using `globals()[]`.

```
varList = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
for index, i in enumerate(varList):
    globals()[i] = index + 1
    print(varList[index], '=', globals()[i])
print(var1,var2,var3)
```

I can confirm this with my two `print()` calls, which give:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
```

and

```
1 2 3
```

respectively.

However, although it seems like I have all the right pieces necessary to be able to do something similar when creating objects of a class, I can't seem to put all the pieces together.

Running the following code

```
class Cars:
    info = ['make', 'model', 'type', 'year']

def metaObject():
    attributeList = []
    myCar = Cars()

    for index, i in enumerate(myCar.info):
        attributeList += ['myCar.'+ i]
        myInfoList = ['Toyota', 'Prius', 'Sedan', 2010]
        
        print(attributeList[index],'=', myInfoList[index])

        globals()[attributeList[index]] = myInfoList[index]

        print(attributeList[index])
        print(globals()[attributeList[index]])

        print('\n')

    print(attributeList)
    print(myInfoList)

metaObject()
```

produces the following output:

```
myCar.make = Toyota 
myCar.make
Toyota

myCar.model = Prius 
myCar.model
Prius


myCar.type = Sedan 
myCar.type
Sedan


myCar.year = 2010 
myCar.year
2010


['myCar.make', 'myCar.model', 'myCar.type', 'myCar.year']
['Toyota', 'Prius', 'Sedan', 2010]
```

However, adding `print(myCar.make)` at the end of my script results in an error `NameError: name 'myCar' is not defined`.

What am I missing here, it seems to me that `myCar` is defined on line 5 of my script?

If, alternatively, at the end of my code—right after calling `metaObject()`—I were to add

```
myCar = Cars()
myCar.make = 'someCarMaker'
print(myCar.make)
```

then I would get the desired result `someCarMaker`.

What would I need to do/change within the definition of `metaObject()` in order to get the result I am am after?

Comment: You can't have a `.` in a variable name.  Stop messing around with `globals()` at least until you understand how classes, objects, and even basic dictionaries work IMO; this is literally the most confusing way possible to teach yourself these concepts.  :)

Comment: I feel like learning classes is precisely what I am trying to do. Do you have a more specific suggestion as to how to better go about it?  As for the code, if I add the following as separate lines of code `myCar = Cars()`, `myCar.make = 'someCarMaker'`, `print(myCar.make)` then I get  the desired result `someCarMaker`.  However, I am having a hard time seeing why that is not happening already in my definition of `metaObject()`.  Can you please provide an example of how I would be able to achieve the desired result within `metaObject()`

Comment: `myCar.make = ...` is not an assignment to a name `myCar.make`; it's short for `myCar.__setattr__('make', ...)`. That doesn't mean you can't add a *key* `'myCar.make'` to the value of `globals()`; it's a `dict` like any other, just one updates the global namespace *when applicable*.

Comment: @ZwiTrader no, it isn't. You are confusing **strings for source code**. You put a bunch of invalid variables names in the global namespace, the ones you created with `myCar.'+ i`. That doesn't **assign an attribute to your object at all**. But the cause of your error is that `myCar` is a *local variable*, not a global one. This is really just a very confused way of trying to understand these concepts

Comment: " I am interested in pursuing it so as to better understand how object creation and globals()[] " **they are completely unrelated**. This is very important to understand. `globals()` will merely retrieve the global namespace, which contains the valid global variables for a module. *Variables are not objects*. Variables *refer* to objects.

Comment: So you created a bunch of names in the global namespace like `myCar.model`, of course, these aren't valid identifiers, but Python lets' you add them since the global namespace is just a plain dictionary. Yous eem to think that `globals()[whatever]` allows the execution of arbitrary code with `whatever`. You'd have to use `eval` or `exec` for that, although in this case, you can use `setattr`. None of these things are really good to try to grok at this moment before you learn the very basics

Comment: If you want to start learning about cars, first you learn to drive. You don't learn about the physics of an internal combustion engine. That comes later, once you have a firm understanding of what a car *does*. `globals()` is an advanced metaprogramming feature in Python. `class` is a fundamental concept. Start with the latter.

Comment: I appreciate any explanations and cautions that have been given so far, but it seems I stepped on some invisible nerve—being as that no one wants to help by providing an actual example of how I might solve my problem.  Instead, I have gotten lots of people telling me that I should not be asking my question in the first place.  That's not very motivating for someone trying to learn. I realize globals() is not inherently related to classes, but is there something wrong with trying to learn how the might be used together? Any examples of how I can achieve my desired result will be appreciated.

Comment: @ZwiTrader actually, if you read my comments, I've given you direct answers to the issue that you are encountering, and direct alternatives, `eval`, `exec`, and `setattr` in particular.

Comment: The reason you're getting a horrified reaction is primarily that we don't want you to hurt yourself (this is the same instinctive reaction many people have to seeing a child poking a fork at an electrical socket -- to yell "DON'T DO THAT!" and make a grab for the child).  The more selfish motivator is that if there are people out in the world writing code like this, there's a chance that someday one of us might have to maintain it, and nobody wants that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to view the global namespace. One, it's a collection of variables (identifiers associated with a value); two, it's a collection of module attributes (whose names can be arbitrary strings).

`globals()['myCar.make'] = 'Toyota'` does not create a variable, because `myCar.make` is not a valid identifier. It does create a module attribute, though, accessible using `getattr`.

```
>>> globals()['myCar.make'] = 'Toyota'
>>> import sys
>>> getattr(sys.modules['__main__'], 'myCar.make')
'Toyota'
```

The assignment does not set the `make` attribute of the object referenced by `myCar` because `myCar.make = ...` is *not* an assignment to a name. It's shorthand for `myCar.__setattr__('make', 'Toyota')`, or in another form, `setattr(myCar, 'make', 'Toyota')`. If you want to dynamically create the attribute, you can do something like

```
name = 'myCar'
attr = 'make'
value = 'Toyota'

setattr(globals()[name], attr, value)
```

---

If you find yourself writing code that looks like this, though, you are almost certainly doing something wrong. If you need the name of a variable to be part of your program's data, then you should be using an explicit `dict`, not the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're attempting to define a class does not make sense.  Give this a try:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, type, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.type = type
        self.year = year

myCar = Car('Toyota', 'Prius', 'Sedan', 2010)
print(myCar)
print(myCar.make)
print(myCar.model)
print(myCar.type)
print(myCar.year)
```

Note that there is only one top level variable (`myCar`), and the individual values are all *attributes* of the `Car` object that `myCar` references.  Your approach doesn't work because you're treating expressions like `myCar.make` as variables, which is not valid.